# How to remove rows in a dataframe whose column values are not in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several different possible values for a particular column. I also have a set that has the column values of rows that I actually care about. I want to update the dataframe such that it removes all rows whose column values are not found in the list I made . How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question then, for a given column `col` you could do something like this:

```
df = df.loc[df[col].isin(your_list)]
```